# Cannot convert return expression in array

Tags: arrays, swift, types

I have an array declared like so:

```
var myArray = [Int]()
```

I also have a function:

```
func myFunc(num:Int) -> [Int] {
    return myArray.append(num)
}
```

I keep getting the error: "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[Int]'"

Can someone please explain to me what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Should be `myArray.append(num)` and then `return myArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `myArray.append(num)` does not return an object of type `[Int]` (it is void, meaning it does not return anything), so you will have to write your code like this:

```
func myFunc(num:Int) -> [Int] {
    myArray.append(num)
    return myArray
}
```

Comment: ah i see, interesting...That fixed it for me, thank you!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

[Swift reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Array/s:FSa6appendFxT_) declares `append` function as follows:

```
mutating func append(_ newElement: Element)
```

Note that the return type is missing, i.e. there is no `->` part in the declaration. What that means is that `append` cannot be used in an expression.

What you need to do is append on one line and return on the other.

Comment: gotcha, makes total sense now. Thanks for the further detailed explanation!

Comment: @user3353890 You are welcome. Swift error messages are sometimes not perfect, so Apple's method documentation could come in handy in situations like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is you are trying to return the return value of Array.append(), which is null. Instead, just do:

```
myArray.append(num)
return myArray
```